# How to make remove class function asynchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, angular, asynchronous

I'm using a custom directive for the images in my angular app, In the directive, I want to add placeholder image until the image loads and the placeholder image has to be applied with a 'no-image' class. This is what I have done:

```
loadImage(image: string) {
    let defaultImage = this._getLocalResource(this._NO_IMAGE);
    this.currentElement.className = 'no-image';
    this.currentElement.src = defaultImage;
    const img = new Image();
    if (image) {
        img.src = image;
    } else {
        img.src = defaultImage;
    }
    img.onload = () => {
        this.currentElement.classList.remove('no-image');
        this.currentElement.src = img.src;
    };
    img.onerror = err => {
        this.currentElement.class = 'no-image';
        this.currentElement.src = defaultImage;
    };
}
```

My problem is when the image loads(inside onload function) the removing of class 'no-image' is taking some time and the loaded image is rendered with the class 'no-image' for a fraction of sec. This is causing unpleasant user experience.

Is there any way that I can assign the loaded image to currentElement.src after the class has been removed successfully, or is there any async way to remove the class?

Comment: Why not just give the image `visibility: hidden` until the "load" handler runs?

Comment: The actual removal of the class from the class list will take almost no time at all. To me the problem is probably that you bother to assign a "src" to the target image before determining whether the real desired image exists. If it starts off hidden, then *nothing* will be shown until the availability is determined.

Comment: @Pointy I need the image to be visible and show the placeholder image instead

Comment: The actual removal of the class from the class list is taking time and it is visible in some cases.

Comment: What's taking time is the HTTP request to fetch the image. Modifying the class list, once the "onload" function is actually called, will take no time at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try delay the
this.currentElement.src = img.src;
line by [settimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: That would not be true asynchronous, It might fail when load takes too much time